# Dropdown menu with image does not align right on Firefox browser

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, dropdown

```css
.dropdown-menu {
font-size: 12px;
}
```

[The dropdown I am working on in chrome and Internet Explorer look like this and it needs to look the same on Firefox browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nApGW.png) Here is the code snippet for the code I am working on. The code below works fine in Internet Explorer and Google Chrome but does not work on Firefox as align: right on img takes the image to the next line in the dropdown menu when viewed in firefox browser. I need help with this as I have tried a lot and I would like to align the text with the image in li tag on Firefox too.
[Here is the image of the dropdown on Firefox browser looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spqGM.png)

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="accountmenu">
                  <li><span id="userli" th:text="'Hi, '+${session.COMMUSER.firstName}+' '+${session.COMMUSER.lastName}"></span></li>
                   <li><a th:href="@{~/aexportal/ProcessUserEdit.do?userId=}+${session.COMMUSER.userId}">My profile</a></li>
                   <li><a th:href="@{~/aexportal/ProcessCompanyEdit.do?tpId=}+${session.COMMUSER.aexTpId}">Company profile</a></li>        
                   <li th:if="${!session.COMMUSER.containsRole('OPERATOR')}"> <a th:href="@{~/aexportal/ProcessTradingPartnerDirectorySearch.do}">Trading Partner Directory</a></li>                 
                    <li th:if="${session.COMMUSER.containsRole('BUYER_ADMIN') or session.COMMUSER.containsRole('SELLER_ADMIN')}"><a th:href="@{~/aexportal/ProcessCompanyAdminConsole.do}">Administration</a></li>
 
                   <li><a th:href="@{http://esupport.aeroxchange.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa}">View and report incidents</a></li>
                   <li><a th:href="@{~/aexportal/ProcessBeforeRegistration.do}">Create another registration</a></li>
                   <li><a th:href="@{~aexportal/training/training_centre.jsp}">User Guides</a></li>
                   <li><span id="productsli" th:text="Products"></span></li>
                   <li><a th:href="@{~/lbts/DisplayAOGPartSearch.do}">AeroAOG <img src="img/aex_bullet_sm.gif" width="15" height="19" border="0" align="right"/></a></li>
                   <li><a th:href="@{~/polc/DisplayPOBuyerConsole.do}">AeroBuy <img src="img/aex_bullet_sm.gif" width="15" height="19" border="0" align="right"/></a></li>
                  <li><a th:href="@{~/commercial-web/show_console}">AeroBuy Commercial<img src="img/aex_bullet_sm.gif" width="15" height="19" border="0" align="right"/></a></li>                                                                                                                                                                        
                   <li><a th:href="@{~/aexportal/DisplayNewACRedirection.do}">New AeroComponent<img src="img/aex_bullet_sm.gif" width="15" height="19" border="0" align="right"/></a></li>
                  <li><a th:href="@{~/ac/DisplayProviderConsole.do}">AeroComponent<img src="img/aex_bullet_sm.gif" width="15" height="19" border="0" align="right"/></a></li>
                  <li><a th:href="@{~/consignment/DisplayConsignmentPartSearch.do?appUser=buyer&amp;newSearch=true}">AeroConsignment<img src="img/aex_bullet_sm.gif" width="15" height="19" border="0" align="right"/></a></li>
                  <li><a th:href="@{~/repair/DisplayRepairConsole.do?console=buyer}">AeroRepair<img src="img/aex_bullet_sm.gif" width="15" height="19" border="0" align="right"/></a></li>
                  <li><a th:href="@{~/aexportal/mktint/mktintPurchaseHome.jsp}">AeroDex<img src="img/aex_bullet_sm.gif" width="15" height="19" border="0" align="right"/></a></li>
                  <li><a th:href="@{~/rfi/DisplayRFIConsole.do}">RFx<img src="img/aex_bullet_sm.gif" width="15" height="19" border="0" align="right"/></a></li>
               <li style="text-align: right; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 1px;"> <button id="logout" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"> Logout </button></li>                   
      </ul>
```

Comment: you forgot to add your css

Comment: you need the <a> and <img> to be aligned with display: inline-block , or float perhaps.  But you are going to need to differertiate between an <a> with an image after it and one that does not.

Comment: #accountmenu > li > a {
 
 display:inline-block;
}

#accountmenu > li > a > img {
 
 float:right;
} -- Hi, I added CSS to the above code as you had mentioned and still it did not align properly.

Answer (score 0):

Desired result would be much easier to accomplish by abandoning `img` tag altogether and setting the icon image via CSS `background` property as such:

```
<ul>
    <li>No Icon Example</li>
    <li>No Icon Example</li>
    <li>No Icon Example</li>
    <li class="icon">Icon Example</li>
    <li class="icon">Icon Example</li>
    <li class="icon">Icon Example</li>
    <li class="icon">Icon Example</li>
    <li class="icon">Icon Example</li>
    <li class="icon">Icon Example</li>
</ul>

ul li {
    height: 30px;
}

ul li.icon {
    background: url("../images/arrow.png") 130px 0 no-repeat;
}
```